# How could I squeeze in a smaller form box on the left of an existing box?

Tags: html, css, html-table

This is what I have currently:

[image]

This is what I'm hoping for:

[image]

I tried tables and width percentages, but I just can't get it right. E.g. this is what I ended up with when I tried this:

```
<table class="toptable">
<tr><td class="cl1">+1</td>
    <td class="cl2">
        <div class="field"><input id="email_phone" class="text" type="text" name="email_phone" maxlength="128"  placeholder="phone number or email" tabindex="1">
            <span class="form_label">(+01 123 4567890)</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

```

```
    .cl1{
    width:20%;
    display:inline;
    }

    .cl2{
    width:80%;
    display:inline;
    }

    .toptable  {
    padding:5px;
    width:200px;
    }
```

[image]

Instead of being side to side, the '+1' shoves to the top of it..

Appreciate any help/pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using 'Col-Md-X' classes in your `<td>` tags?

Similar to percentages you can divide your space into 12 sections.
Replacing your cl1 and cl2 classes with `class="col-md-3"` and `class="col-md-9"` will give your prefix section 1/4 of the space, and the number section the remaining 3/4 space. 
You can also change the numbers in `col-md` to divide your table row in different ways.

```
     <table class="toptable">
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-3">+1</td>
            <td class="col-md-9">
                <div class="field">
                    <input id="email_phone" class="text" type="text" name="email_phone" maxlength="128" placeholder="phone number or email" tabindex="1">
                    <span class="form_label">(+01 123 4567890)</span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer James, I unfortunately cannot use bootstrap, we have a lot of CSS styling on the page and the bootstrap libraries mess it all up :/ Would you know of a way doing this without bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve it using table you can do something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td> <span>+1</span> </td> //set it like 20%
    <td> <input ...> </td> //60%
    <td></td> //20%
</tr>
```

or use div and use positionig of elements depending on look you want to achieve
like:

```
<div><span>+1</span></div> //set width to 20%
<div><input ...></div> // set width to 60% 
                       //center input nad make divs to float left
```